# How to render a Webix list as blank when no item in it

Tags: javascript, webix

I am using webix uploader and linking it to a list view to display the uploaded items. The code has been taken from [http://docs.webix.com/desktop__file_upload.html][1] and looks like below :

```
view:"form", rows: [
                    { 
                        view: "uploader", value: 'Upload file', 
                        name:"files",
                        link:"mylist",  upload:"js/upload.js" 
                    },
                    {
                        view:"list",  id:"mylist", type:"uploader",
                        autoheight:true, borderless:true    
                    },
```

However, when the page loads and no file has been uploaded, then it is showing an empty line with 'undefined' being printed in the list placeholder. After uploading the file, it disappears and the uploaded filename is getting shown.
Before anything is uploaded, I am vainly trying the below lines code in a function to prevent displaying of that ugly  "undefined" string :

```
 $$('mylist').clearAll();
```

Is there a way to get rid of this ugly print when the page loads. Likewise the above link which I am referring to, I want nothing to be shown before anything is uploaded. How can I achieve that ?
 Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a snippet demonstrating your problem

Comment: @fabien-michel I am sorry when I am trying to reproduce the same thing when I write this snippet. I am sharing the snippet link here http://webix.com/snippet/5375567c, however when I am doing the same thing in my actual application, a blank line just beneath the 'Upload a file' button  with 'undefined' printed in place of the uploaded file name is getting rendered when the page loads before any upload activity.

Comment: @fabien-michel Just to add that , in that above snippet I am not able to reproduce the actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check there isn't an erroneous setValue() on your form component like in this snippet : http://webix.com/snippet/ea405e4c

Comment: Correct, somewhere something of that sort is happening. I have commented out few portions of my code and it just disappeared. I need to find out where exactly it is getting set to "". Thanks a lot!

Comment: however is there a way to prevent it. The snippet you shared, I tried to change responsible statement by assigning some value instead of "" as $$('myform').elements.files.setValue("hello"); Still I found that the 'undefined' is retained. In my code setValue is setting value to various things and none of them is assigning "" , still it is coming.

Comment: You are true settings values globally on the form will display "undefined" into the files list. I see two workarounds :
1. Use setValues in update mode `$$('myform').setValues({name:'truc'}, true);` : http://webix.com/snippet/0f974f34
2. Add empty array for "files" into setValues object : `$$('myform').setValues({name:'truc', files:[]});`

Comment: Awesome. files:[ ] is working fine for me. Thanks a lot!